# How To Optimize Looping?

Tags: apex, loop, custom-metadata

I've written a utility class that enables a Custom Metadata Type mapping for Object to Object data cloning. I'd like our Admin team to be able to add/create/adjust the Fields on either object without requiring code changes.

This utility will also be used across many different Objects and business processes and reduces our hard-coded business process. I'm running into an issue however with performance and bulkification, specifically because I've written this with a loop inside of another loop. I'm still learning Apex, and don't have a resource within the company to go to, so I'm hoping the Stack Exchange community is able to help guide me in a direction for a fix.

Essentially, I need to get the "from" field's value from the original Object and map them to fields on another object to the "to" field. Are ways I can achieve this without having to loop through each Mapping record for each record I pass to the method? An example of how this would be used, is that we're using this to map Lead and Contact values to the Individual Object for GDPR.

```
public static List<sObject> mapRecords(List<sObject> passRecords,
                                       String fromObjectName, String toObjectName){

    List<sObject> records = new List<sObject>();
    List<Field_Mapping__mdt> mapping = 
              [Select From_Field__c, To_Field__c from Field_Mapping__mdt 
                 where Mapped_From_Object__c =: fromObjectName AND
                       Mapped_To_Object__c =: toObjectName AND Is_Active__c = True];
    System.debug('Field Mapping Records: ' + mapping);

    For(sObject p : passRecords){
        sObject record = FieldMapperUtility.createObject(toObjectName);
        For(Field_Mapping__mdt m : mapping){
            record.put(m.To_Field__c, p.get(m.From_Field__c));
        }

        records.Add(record);
    }

    system.debug('sObject Size: '+ records.size());
    Return records;
}

public static sObject createObject(String typeName) {
    Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName);
    return targetType.newSObject(); 
}
```

Comment: well, it is bulkified as you do the soql only once presuming that the method `mapRecords` is only invoked once per transaction (i.e. on a list of contacts or leads). Are you running out of CPU time? You could also pass sobjectTypes rather than strings as it seems like the caller knows what type they are dealing with. Or use `Type.forName(toObjectName).newInstance()`

Comment: @heyaapl - Your logic is neat. Though querying Custom Metadata does not count against SOQL query limits, it is still a good practice to reduce the number of times you query and in this case, you are already doing that.
The only concern I see here is the number of records that you pass to map records method. If that number is high, you might have to use a Batch process to do this to not hit the limits. Here is the link,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm
Let me know for further questions.

Comment: It does count against query row limit.